# vue.js – menu tree with quick filter: collapsible and filter doesn't work together

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

#### Motivation

I want to create a menu tree with a search bar to highlight menu items. I came up with the following implementation:

```js
const treeConfig = [
  {
    label: 'User',
    children: [
      {
        label: 'User group'
      },
      {
        label: 'Permissions'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'Tests',
    children: [
      {
        label: 'Unit tests'
      },
      {
        label: 'Visual regression tests'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'Other stuff'
  }
];

Vue.component('tree', {
  template: '#tree',
  props: ['nodes'],
  data() {
    return {
      showChildren: true
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleChildren() {
      this.showChildren = !this.showChildren;
    }
  }
});

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    quicksearch: ''
  },
  computed: {
    nodes() {
      const self = this;
      
      function getTree(nodes) {
        return nodes.map((node) => {
          node.label_ = node.label;
          node.label_ = node.label.replace(new RegExp(self.quicksearch, 'gi'), '<mark>$&</mark>');
          if (node.children) {
            node.children = getTree(node.children);
          }
          return node;
        });
      }
      
      return getTree(treeConfig);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="search" placeholder="Quick search" v-model="quicksearch">
  <tree :nodes="nodes"></tree>
</div>

<template id="tree">
  <ul>
    <li
      v-for="node in nodes"
    >
    <span
      v-if="node.children"
      @click="toggleChildren()"
    >
      <i v-show="!showChildren">+</i>
      <i v-show="showChildren">-</i>
    </span>
    <span v-html="node.label_"></span>
    <tree
      v-if="node.children"
      v-show="showChildren"
      :nodes="node.children"
    ></tree>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

#### Problem

With the code above the subtrees cannot be collapsed indepentendly. A click on one of the `+` or `-` collapse each subtree.

#### Second approach

So I've tried to use a `tree-item` component instead of the `tree` component:

```js
const treeConfig = [
  {
    label: 'User',
    children: [
      {
        label: 'User group'
      },
      {
        label: 'Permissions'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'Tests',
    children: [
      {
        label: 'Unit tests'
      },
      {
        label: 'Visual regression tests'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'Other stuff'
  }
];

Vue.component('tree-item', {
  template: '#tree-item',
  props: ['node'],
  data() {
    return {
      showChildren: true
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleChildren() {
      this.showChildren = !this.showChildren;
    }
  }
});

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    quicksearch: '',
    title: 'Hello filtered tree!'
  },
  computed: {
    nodes() {
      const self = this;
      
      function getTree(nodes) {
        return nodes.map((node) => {
          node.label_ = node.label;
          node.label_ = node.label.replace(new RegExp(self.quicksearch, 'gi'), '<mark>$&</mark>');
          if (node.children) {
            node.children = getTree(node.children);
          }
          return node;
        });
      }
      
      return getTree(treeConfig);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="search" placeholder="Quick search" v-model="quicksearch">
  <ul>
    <tree-item
      v-for="node in nodes"
      :node="node"
    ></tree-item>
  </ul>
</div>

<template id="tree-item">
  <li>
    <span
      v-if="node.children"
      @click="toggleChildren()"
    >
      <i v-show="!showChildren">+</i>
      <i v-show="showChildren">-</i>
    </span>
    <span v-html="node.label_"></span>
    <ul
      v-if="node.children"
      v-show="showChildren"
    >
      <tree-item
        v-for="node in node.children"
        :node="node"
      ></tree-item>
    </ul>
  </li>
</template>
```

#### Problem

Now it's possible to collapse each subtree separately, but the quickfilter doesn't work. It seems that the `nodes` object isn't reactive.

Where's my thinking mistake? Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to be a problem with arrays. just add `:key="node.label_"` to your `tree-item` tag in the template, that's it.

Comment: Interesting! and it doesn't need a watcher and created hook. I will check this. Bye the way: thank you ;-)

Comment: Strange. I thought this solves the problem, but it leads to another one. The filter works a little bit weird now. Tried to search after **sss**: no matches expected, but **Permissions** and **Visual regression tests** are still highlighted. With the solution from @Ekushisu it works as expected.

Comment: I do not change any props on the child component, only the tree config will be transformed.

Comment: to keep the solution simpler with your code here is a quick and dirty one: replace `:key="node.label_"` with `:key="node.id"` and add `node.id = Guid()` before your regex line. `Guid()` some basic incremental id generator function. Sorry for the quick  judgement:).

Comment: no problem ;-) – I'm using `Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15)` to create an uid and yes, it seems to work right. But I think it has some performance costs. So I will use the accepted answer for the moment.

Comment: i call it "Guid" but there is no need to be so complicated (a simple integer incrementation using yield syntax will do the trick). you just need to switch between two set of IDs. The idea is : Vuejs will trigger rendering when the list has changed (because of caching). otherwise your welcome ;).

Comment: Ok, I like your approach. Please update your answer and you will get the points 

Comment: After some research I understand the problem now. It depends on the caching behavior. Other contributed plugins used this approach too and it seems to be widespread to use an unique id. So I will give you the points ;-)

Comment: glad to be able to help you, much more for the feedback :D

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look to this : [Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)
When your computed is freshly computed by the change of the quicksearch value, it doesn't trigger the reconstruction of other components (in this case the tree-item) because it don't watch in the object deeply.

The simple work around here, is to entierely reaffect the new array mapping result.

```js
const treeConfig = [
  {
    label: 'User',
    children: [
      {
        label: 'User group'
      },
      {
        label: 'Permissions'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'Tests',
    children: [
      {
        label: 'Unit tests'
      },
      {
        label: 'Visual regression tests'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'Other stuff'
  }
];

Vue.component('tree-item', {
  template: '#tree-item',
  props: ['node'],
  data() {
    return {
      showChildren: true
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleChildren() {
      this.showChildren = !this.showChildren;
    }
  },
  watch : {
    node(n) {
      console.log(n)
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log(this.node);
  }
});

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    quicksearch: '',
    title: 'Hello filtered tree!',
    nodes : []
  },
  methods : {    
    getNodes() {
      const self = this;
      
      function getTree(nodes) {
        return nodes.map((node) => {
          node.label_ = node.label;
          node.label_ = node.label.replace(new RegExp(self.quicksearch, 'gi'), '<mark>$&</mark>');
          if (node.children) {
            node.children = getTree(node.children);
          }
          return node;
        });
      }
      
      return getTree(treeConfig);
    }
  },
  created(){
    this.nodes = this.getNodes();
  },
  watch : {
    quicksearch(q) {
      this.nodes = this.getNodes();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="search" placeholder="Quick search" v-model="quicksearch">
  <ul>
    <tree-item
      v-for="node in nodes"
      :node="node"
    ></tree-item>
  </ul>
</div>

<template id="tree-item">
  <li>
    <span
      v-if="node.children"
      @click="toggleChildren()"
    >
      <i v-show="!showChildren">+</i>
      <i v-show="showChildren">-</i>
    </span>
    <span v-html="node.label_"></span>
    <ul
      v-if="node.children"
      v-show="showChildren"
    >
      <tree-item
        v-for="node in node.children"
        :node="node"
      ></tree-item>
    </ul>
  </li>
</template>
```

Comment: Looks promising. Had a look at the doc, but may I do not fully understand it. I will try to test your change on my real use case.